# Sudden increase in available hard drive space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I was copying large files over to my computer for video editing and keeping an eye on available hard drive space I knew I should have had just enough space to put everything. However, as I was getting close to filling up my hard drive, the available free space suddenly jumped by about 30GB. Any idea what happened?

Comment: Do you use NTFS compression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen with Transactional NTFS. The free space is used for storing the transaction, once the transaction is committed the free space can be reclaimed.

Answer (score 1):

The OS automatically emptied your trash, deleted TMP files, etc....

Happens on Windows and OS X.

What is your OS?

Comment: Windows 7. I emptied my trash earlier already and actually had to uninstall a few programs and clean up the computer a little before i transfered files to my computer. I didn't do anything with the temp files but can temp files really add up to 30GB?

Comment: The other thing that can happen is a delayed recognition by the OS of additional space...

Answer (score 0):

Some of those Windows files of folders that "automatically" grow huge (C:\SystemVolumeInformation, C:\Recovery), sometimes they are also automatically cleaned.

There is also [Storage Sense](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/manage-drive-space-with-storage-sense-654f6ada-7bfc-45e5-966b-e24aded96ad5), or that time when Microsoft decided that files that are stored on cloud (OneDrive) can be deleted by the system when you are low on space.

Pagefile.sys can also shrink in size if you needed a lot of virtual memory before and then you have closed some memory hungry applications.

Generally speaking, Windows does the same as humans: it uses all the disk space it wants while it can, and when free space is scarce it starts cleaning things up.